# Не заносит данные в sqlite таблицу

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

У меня есть БД database_one. Есть this_sb, tmp_cap - списки, в которых хранятся значения, которые я хочу поместить в БД. Чтобы это было вида:

```
-----------------
| sb_1 | cap_11 | 
| ------------- |
| sb_1 | cap_12 |
| ------------- |
|     .....     |
| ------------- |
| sb_1 | cap_25 |
-----------------
```

**Внесение данных в таблицу:**

```
this_sb = ['sb_1']
tmp_cap = ['cap_11', 'cap_12', 'cap_13', 'cap_14', 'cap_15', 'cap_21', 'cap_22', 'cap_23', 'cap_24', 'cap_25']

this_db = 'database_one'
database_path = f'databases/{this_db}.db'
connect = sqlite3.connect(database_path)
cursor = connect.cursor()

#Занесение в бд:
    for caps in tmp_cap:
       try:
           sql = "INSERT INTO stock_bins (stock_bin_number, capsule_number) VALUES(?, ?)"
           params = (this_sb, caps)
           cursor.execute(sql, params)
       except Exception as esc:
           print('Не удалось занести ', this_sb, ' ', caps, ' в бд!')
```

Ошибки не выдает, но когда я смотрю в БД, то ничего не вижу (ничего не добавилось). Подскажите, почему так получается?

**На всякий случай прилагаю код создания этой таблицы**:

```
 new_db_name = 'database_one'
 def create_tables(new_db_name):
 try:
     new_db_name = f'{new_db_name}.db'
     folder_name = 'databases'
     folder_path = f'{folder_name}/'
     if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
         os.makedirs(folder_path)
     # Подключаемся к базе данных в папке databases
     connect = sqlite3.connect(folder_path + new_db_name)
     cursor = connect.cursor()
     # И создаем таблицу:
     cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE stock_bins
                                             (stock_bin_number TEXT,
                                             capsule_number TEXT)""")
 except sqlite3.Error as error:
     print("Ошибка при создании таблиц", error)

 create_db(new_db_name)
```

Comment: Забыли вызвать `commit`? После изменений в базе вызывайте `connect.commit()`

Comment: @gil9red точно.. Спасибо :)

Comment: @Iamready,чтобы в будущем таких ошибок не было,можно в  `connect` поставить параметр `autocommit=True` и вам не придется каждый раз писать `commit`

Answer (score 1):

При внесении изменений в базу (создание/удаление/модификация) потребуется вызвать сохранение через метод `commit()`:

При вставке, но если вставка через цикл, то лучше после цикла вызвать `commit()`:

```
connect = sqlite3.connect(database_path)
cursor = connect.cursor()

#Занесение в бд:
    for caps in tmp_cap:
       try:
           sql = "INSERT INTO stock_bins (stock_bin_number, capsule_number) VALUES(?, ?)"
           params = (this_sb, caps)
           cursor.execute(sql, params)
       except Exception as esc:
           print('Не удалось занести ', this_sb, ' ', caps, ' в бд!')

connect.commit()
```

При создании таблицы:

```
connect = sqlite3.connect(folder_path + new_db_name)
cursor = connect.cursor()
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE stock_bins
                  (stock_bin_number TEXT,
                   capsule_number TEXT)""")
connect.commit()
```

---

Если использовать `with`, то вызов `commit` будет автоматический после выхода кода из `with`, пример:

```
with sqlite3.connect(folder_path + new_db_name) as connect:
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE stock_bins
                      (stock_bin_number TEXT,
                       capsule_number TEXT)""")
```